# DIV outside container

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

I have a problem with the div that goes out of the container. When a green div touches the edge of a page, the page does not cut it, but adds a horizontal page shift. I use bootstrap4. How to avoid this?

Thanks for help.

Live: https://jsfiddle.net/Cedec/mu2f0whr/

```css
#section2 img {
  float:right;
}

#section2 {
  margin-top:100px;
}

#section2 h2 {
  color: #323232;
  font-size: 70px;
  font-weight: 800;
  float: left;
  line-height: 80px;
  margin-top: 70px;
}

#section2 p{
  color: #494e53;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 30px;
}


.txt2 {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.bg2{
  background-color: #00a998;
  height: 320px;
  z-index: -5;
    margin-top: -550px;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<section id="section2">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-5">
            <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hGq0Rd/111.png" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-7">
            <div class="txt2">
            <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. </p>
            
            
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12 bg2"></div>
        </div>   
      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Use css property as body {overflow-x:hidden}

Comment: Well, you break the `.col-lg-12` by giving it a `margin-left: 100px;`.

Comment: @NileshSutar Thanks! Now all is good!

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, the problem is that you're overriding `col-lg-12` margins and that breaks it's purpose. you should have your class 'bg2' to a div as a child of that `col-lg-12` and also give it a `position: relative` to keep it in the background.

https://jsfiddle.net/mu2f0whr/6/

Answer (score -1):

Adding `overflow: hidden` to `#section2` hides everything that goes beyond your container.

Comment: Reading your answer gives me the idee you have no clue what `overflow` is for.